# 2 Simultâneous access to the Android câmera with Kivy + Jnius

Tags: python, camera, virtual-reality, oculus

I need to create an app that works on a VR glasses, as in this example below:

But I have two problems:

1. I can not make two simultaneous accesses to the camera and create two widgets.
2. I can not make the widgets created in kv file (in this case a label) stay on the camera, to write information about the view.

Any way to create this dual camera widget and write it over?

my code:

main:

```
__version__ = '1.0'

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty, \
    NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from jnius import autoclass, PythonJavaClass, java_method, cast
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread

PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
Camera = autoclass('android.hardware.Camera')
SurfaceView = autoclass('android.view.SurfaceView')
LayoutParams = autoclass('android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams')

class PreviewCallback(PythonJavaClass):

    __javainterfaces__ = ('android.hardware.Camera$PreviewCallback', )

    def __init__(self, callback):
        super(PreviewCallback, self).__init__()
        self.callback = callback

class SurfaceHolderCallback(PythonJavaClass):
    __javainterfaces__ = ('android.view.SurfaceHolder$Callback', )

    def __init__(self, callback):
        super(SurfaceHolderCallback, self).__init__()
        self.callback = callback

    @java_method('(Landroid/view/SurfaceHolder;III)V')
    def surfaceChanged(self, surface, fmt, width, height):
        self.callback(fmt, width, height)

class AndroidWidgetHolder(Widget):
    view = ObjectProperty(allownone=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._old_view = None
        from kivy.core.window import Window
        self._window = Window
        kwargs['size_hint'] = (None, None)
        super(AndroidWidgetHolder, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_view(self, instance, view):
        activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
        activity.addContentView(view, LayoutParams(*self.size))
        view.setZOrderOnTop(True)
        view.setX(self.x)
        view.setY(self._window.height - self.y - self.height)

class AndroidCamera(Widget):

    index = NumericProperty(0)

    __events__ = ('on_preview_frame', )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self._holder = None
        self._android_camera = None
        super(AndroidCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._holder = AndroidWidgetHolder(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
        self.add_widget(self._holder)
        self.start()

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def stop(self):
        if self._android_camera is None:
            return
        self._android_camera.setPreviewCallback(None)
        self._android_camera.release()
        self._android_camera = None
        self._holder.view = None


    @run_on_ui_thread
    def start(self):

        if self._android_camera is not None:
            return

        self._android_camera = Camera.open(self.index)

        self._android_surface = SurfaceView(PythonActivity.mActivity)
        surface_holder = self._android_surface.getHolder()

        self._android_surface_cb = SurfaceHolderCallback(self._on_surface_changed)
        surface_holder.addCallback(self._android_surface_cb)

        self._holder.view = self._android_surface
        self._holder2.view = self._android_surface

    def _on_surface_changed(self, fmt, width, height):

        params = self._android_camera.getParameters()
        params.setPreviewSize(width, height)
        self._android_camera.setParameters(params)
        self._previewCallback = PreviewCallback(self._on_preview_frame)

        self._android_camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(self._previewCallback);
        self._android_camera.setPreviewDisplay(self._android_surface.getHolder())
        self._android_camera.startPreview();

    def _on_preview_frame(self, camera, data):
        self.dispatch('on_preview_frame', camera, data)
        self._android_camera.addCallbackBuffer(data)

    def on_preview_frame(self, camera, data):
        pass


    def on_size(self, instance, size):
        if self._holder:
            self._holder.size = size

    def on_pos(self, instance, pos):
        if self._holder:
            self._holder.pos = pos

class vrtest(App, BoxLayout):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('qrcode.kv')

    camera_size = ListProperty([640, 480])

    xpos = NumericProperty(-190)
    ypos = 25

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(vrtest, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        self._camera = AndroidCamera(
                size=self.camera_size,
                size_hint=(None, None),
                pos=(self.xpos, self.ypos))
        self.add_widget(self._camera)

    def start(self):
        self._camera.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':

vrtest().run()
```

kv:

```
FloatLayout:
    Label:
        text: 'Label Test12345678987654321'
        pos_hint:{'x':0, 'y':0}
```

Comment: unable to download the file from your link, share your file or code some another way or site

Comment: I just changed the links. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: James Z, thanks for the Edit. Im new here..